# Python convert large data arrays to grid for matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, grid

i want to use a defined function to convert the input data to grid-arrays, which can be used by matplotlib. For an example with bigger data look at my [griddata.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59720953/griddata.zip) file.
The arrays look like e.g.: `x = [0,1.0,2.0], y = [0.0,10.0,20.0], z = [0.0, 20.0, 50.0]` meaning, that they have the same length, and z should be the plotted on the x-y-grid.:
Basically, there were some efforts to answer this before. A possible solution was given by M4rtini:

```
from numpy import linspace, meshgrid
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
    "Convert 3 column data to matplotlib grid"
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x): max(x):1j * resX, min(y): max(y):1j * resY]
    Z = griddata(np.array(zip(x, y)), np.array(z), (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
    return grid_x, grid_y, Z

x =[0,1.0,2.0]
y = [0.0,10.0,20.0]
z = [0.0, 20.0, 50.0]

X,Y,Z =  grid(x,y,z)

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

The plot output should look like this for the large data file: [Image of Plot output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59720953/figure.png)

Comment: I think it's bad practice to name the variable and the function the same. Perhaps you can try just `print grid(x,y,z)` and then worry about the formatting of the output. Also, I think you need to add `from scipy.interpolate import griddata`

Comment: thanks, I updated my description, nevertheless the return value is None.

Comment: can you share the entire code, as is (instead of in 2 parts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from numpy import linspace, meshgrid
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
    "Convert 3 column data to matplotlib grid"
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x): max(x):1j * resX, min(y): max(y):1j * resY]
    Z = griddata(np.array(zip(x, y)), np.array(z), (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
    return grid_x, grid_y, Z


x =[0,1.0,2.0]
y = [0.0,10.0,20.0]
z = [0.0, 20.0, 50.0]

X,Y,Z =  grid(x,y,z)

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

Any of the other interpolation methods fails for this test data.

[image]

Comment: thanks, for my minimal example this works perfectly, but i can't figure out why it doesn't work for large arrays as given here [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59720953/griddata.zip), any idea?

Comment: `from pylab import *` overwrites the griddata from scipy. Since pylab has it's own griddata function. Which is why you should never use `from xx import * ` one of the two imports need to change.

Comment: For this data you can also change the method to `linear` or `cubic` for possibly better results.

Comment: okay it was really a problem with from pylab import *

Comment: I just deleted it, and the other issue is the datatype of the array, it should be the same, which can be changed with: np.dtype(('float64')))